# Obtain information with a txt

Tags: r

I have a question in R. I have an Excel column that all its lines are made up of links. 
I want to create a bot or some way, to get the info from that link (all info is plain text .txt). 
Do you know any way to extract that information and meters in the right column? Greetings and thank you !.

I tried to read.delim but I have this problem.

```
read.delim("http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0017969.txt")
```

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     more columns than column names

On another hand I tried with:

```
read.txt("http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023294.txt"))
```

But many lines are created for me. Do you know any way to join those lines?

THANKS!

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a scraper to all the links in your Excel files? and extract information from all the links?

Comment: The contents of what you are looking at seems to be HTML rather than simple plain text. You need to use a function that can parse the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to join lines of text in a vector together, you can use `paste(x, collapse = "\n")`

It's probably best to define a simple function to read the contents of a url and return all the lines pasted together:

```r
get_txt <- function(link) paste0(readLines(link, warn = FALSE), collapse = "\n")
```

Which you could use like this:

```
x <- get_txt("http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023294.txt")
x
#> [1] "<div class=\"std especificaciones content-section section-2\"><div class=\
#> "column-left\">\n\t\t\t\t<h3>General</h3>\n\t\t\t\t<table class=\"data-table\" i
#> d=\"product-attribute-specs-table-1\">\n\t\t\t\t\t<col width=\"25%\" />\n\t\t\t\
#> t\t<col />\n\t\t\t\t\t<tbody><tr>\n\t\t                   \t\t\t<th class=\"labe
#> l\" data-attribute-code=\"brands\">Marca</th>\t<td class=\"data\">WESTERN DIGITA
#> L </td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr><tr>\n\t\t                   \t\t\t<th class=\"lab
#> el\" data-attribute-code=\"warranty\">GarantÃ­a</th>\t<td class=\"data\">2 aÃ±os
#>  de garantÃ­a</td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr><tr>\n\t\t                   \t\t\t<th 
#> class=\"label\" data-attribute-code=\"part_number\">Part Number</th>\t<td class=
#> \"data\">WDBWLG0060HBK-EESN </td>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr><tr>\n\t\t ... <truncated>
```

You can see this is a single text string:

```r
length(x)
#> [1] 1
```